# Ajax appending nonce to js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm getting a unique nonce (i think a timestamp) appended to all and any of my js files every time I send a request to my rails web service:

[image: errors]

I'm fairly sure the error has to do with the ajax call, because of [jquery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which states `cache:true` in your ajax request will stop ajax from  appending "_={timestamp}" to the get parameters.

I have set `cache: true` with no luck.  How else can I stop these nonces from being applied?

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', api_key);
   },
   cache: true,
   dataType: 'html',
   type: 'GET',
   url: url+'/gwsearch/ajax_search?d1='+d1_val+'&d2='+d2_val,
   crossDomain: true,
   success:function(result) {
      $("#display").html(result);
   },
   error: function(result) {
      $('#display').html('Unauthorized client.');
   }
});
```

Comment: Show your AJAX call code.

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that. added.

Comment: what if you set the "data" parameter in your params to ajax, eg { d1: d1_val, d2: d2_val }, do you get the same issue?

Comment: @SebastianMotraghi same issue.

Comment: The URL in your image isn't the URL that the AJAX request is being sent to. That nonce is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @Barmar are you saying it's not coming from my ajax request?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. If it were coming from your AJAX request, it would be `/gwsearch/ajax_search?d1=something&d2=something&_=timestamp`

Comment: well the request url for the js is: Request URL:https://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/application-57f3d612b25edf9087c9c147564d3b17.js?_=1391024812290.  i see what you're saying, but maybe it handles assets differently and only applies the timestamp to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using an ajax prefilter:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) {
options.cache = true;
});
```

Comment: awesome, just what I was looking for